# How to use placeholder in select box if it is created with v-for?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

**Update:**

Due to my own fault of not mentioning, that `tool` is created in a `v-for` loop during render, I couldn't apply the proposed answers although they might have been correct.

In the end I did a workaround by adding following `css sudo element` to the parent of the `select` element:

```
&::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'Paragraph';
  margin-right: .83rem;
  font-size: .83rem;
  place-self: center;
}
```

and setting it to `display: none`, when an item is selected.

**Original Question:**

I'm creating a `select` element in `vue 3` with help of `v-for`:

```
<template>
    <select v-model="tool.action" @change="selectType(tool.action)">
        <option v-for="option in options" :key="option" :value="option.value">{{ option.text }}</option>
    </select>
</template>

<script setup>
const options: [
    { text: 'Heading 1', value: 'h1' },
    { text: 'Heading 2', value: 'h2' },
    { text: 'Heading 3', value: 'h3' },
    { text: 'Paragraph', value: 'p' },
]
</script>
```

Now I want to set a `placeholder` text in the `select box` to `Paragraph`. Usually it would work like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="p" selected>Paragraph</option>
</select>
```

but `v-for` removes the option of setting `selected` manually so how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<select>`'s *placeholder* is usually disabled and not one of the available options. You can do that with an `<option>` *before* your `v-for` of selectable `<option>`s:

```html
<template>
    <select v-model="tool.action" @change="selectType(tool.action)">
        <option disabled value="">Placeholder Option</option> 
        <option v-for="option in options" :key="option" :value="option.value">{{ option.text }}</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-placeholder-in-select?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyOptions.vue)

If you actually want to set the `<select>`'s *initial value*, you could set the `<select>`'s model (i.e., `tool.action`) to the desired value:

```html
<script setup>
⋮
tool.action = 'p' // initialize to 'Paragraph' option's value
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-initial-value-for-select?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyOptions.vue)

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
    <select v-model="tool.action" @change="selectType(tool.action)">
        <option value="p">Paragraph</option>
        <option v-for="option in options" :key="option" :value="option.value">{{ option.text }}</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

and then, set the default value of tool.action to "p".